# Windows installer does not boot on windows xp

Tags: installation

i have installed Windows installer wubi.exe but does not boot, how to dual-boot? how to initialize ubuntu, i did it on windows xp

Answer (score 1):

Try mounting the iso file in a usb disk in windows using rufus http://rufus.akeo.ie/ this will create a mountable usb disk. Restart your computer with usb stick plugged in, it will automatically take it to ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you ran Wubi on Windows XP, followed all the steps in the setup, choose reboot at the end, and then your PC didn't boot into Ubuntu after that?

If so you might need to change the Boot settings. In Windows, Right-Click "My Computer", click Properties-->Advanced Tab-->Startup and Recovery-->Settings. From here you can change the default OS to Boot from and also add a Wait period for you to select an Alternative OS during boot.

Answer (score 0):

Adan's solution might work, but this answer is better. Reinstall. Something obviously went wrong so just add/remove programs uninstall Ubuntu and install again. Ubuntu in the Wubi install is treated like an App. If you just installed it and it failed use my answer. If you have data that you love on there then uses Adan's answer.